# Creating a sliced list from a list

Tags: python-3.x

If I have a list with 600,000 elements

The list I have is quite complicated, and has nothing to do with sequence or order, but let's use this one with 600,000 elements as an example:

```
main_list = list(range(0,1200000,2)
```

and if I want to to create a list that slices the main_list into a new list likes this:

```
sub_list =  [main_list[0:100], main_list[100:200], main_list[200:300], main_list[300:400], ...]
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Something like `sub_list = [main_list[x:x+100] for x in range(0, len(main_list), 100)]` or am I misunderstanding what you're trying to do?

Comment: What does "*has nothing to do with the sequence or order*" mean? You want to split the main list into smaller sub-lists with random elements from the main list? random buckets? random number of sub-lists? Post an expected output that matches the description, because the previous comment does match the new list sample.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson thanks this is what I'm looking for.

Comment: @GinoMempin I have a list with random number, so I use the list in the question as an easy example for asking. Thanks for asking